vaex rolling window with time index
Does the vaex python library support rolling window with time index just like the following pandas api?
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html
I can only see that it supports fixed size windows of size n from their api (ctrl + F for rolling)
https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html
